# Script in ArcGIS Pro does not work in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-pro, feature-class, spyder

I wrote a script to rename and sort feature classes in a database into datasets based on a portion of the feature class name. It works without a hitch with ArcGIS Pro 2.9.1 when using Spyder 5.1.5 running Python 3.7.11 64-Bit. I copy the .py script into the ArcMap 10.8.2  Python window and while it succeeds in creating the datasets, it does not convert the feature classes into the datasets. I don't see any difference in documentation for the tool in ArcGIS Pro vs ArcMap.

What else could explain the failure of the script to run the tool?

```py
import arcpy
import os

# Define workspace and category names
# These can be easily changed for working with different databases and their corresponding categories
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\PSU\Geog485\FinalProject\FinalProjScratch\FinalProjScratch.gdb"
categories = ["Geology", "Hydrology", "Vegetation", "Soils"]

# Define dictionaries and list of correctly named feature classes
catDictionary = {}
catKeys = {}
preNamedFcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*ln") + arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*pt") + arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*py")
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(26912)

# Define function for populating dictionaries with category as keys
def popDictionaries(category):
    if not category in catDictionary:
        catDictionary[category] = dataset    
    if not category in catKeys:
        catKeys[category] = category[0:3].upper()
    
try:
    
    # Check for existence of datasets and create them if they don't exist
    # Populate dictionaries with datasets and category codes with category names as keys for both
    for category in categories:
        if arcpy.Exists(os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, category)):
            dataset = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, category)
            popDictionaries(category)
        else:
            dataset = arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(arcpy.env.workspace, category, sr)
            popDictionaries(category)
     
    # Update names of each feature class based on feature class shape type
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
        desc = arcpy.da.Describe(fc)
        fcType = desc["shapeType"]
        categoryCode = fc[5:8]
        if not fc in preNamedFcs:
            if fcType == "Polyline":
                newName = fc + "_ln"
            if fcType == "Polygon":
                newName = fc + "_py"
            if fcType == "Point":
                newName = fc + "_pt"
                
            # Read renamed feature classes for category codes and sort them into dataset based on dictionaries' shared keys
            for cat in categories:
                if categoryCode == catKeys[cat]:
                    arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(fc, catDictionary[cat], newName)
                    arcpy.management.Delete(fc)
                    
        # Repeat the above process for feature classes already named correctly
        # Name copied feature classes with a temporary "_new" suffix
        else:
            newName = fc + "_new"
            for cat in categories:
                if categoryCode == catKeys[cat]:
                    arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(fc, catDictionary[cat], newName)
                    arcpy.management.Delete(fc)
                    
    # Read through datasets to identify and rename feature classes with the "_new" suffix
    datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets("*")
    datasets.append('')
    for dataset in datasets:
        fc_names = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*new", "", dataset)
        for fc_name in fc_names:
            arcpy.management.Rename(fc_name, fc_name[:-4])
    
except:
    print(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to specify what the "failure" is...  Is there an error?  What diagnostics have you added?  What output does it show?

Comment: I haven't read your code but ArcGIS Pro is compatible with Python 3, while ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap/ArcCatalog) is only compatible with Python 2. So you can't expect to copy and paste a script from one to the other and just expect it to work.

Comment: I think any try/except statements should be removed while testing and from code presented here because they can mask otherwise useful error messages.

Answer (score 0):

arcpy.da.Describe is not available for Python2

Replace the two lines using the da.Describe methodology

```
desc = arcpy.da.Describe(fc)
fcType = desc["shapeType"]
```

With these old Describe methodology

```
desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
fcType = desc.shapeType
```